# Can we restrict spring boot rabbitmq message processing only between specific timings?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Using Spring boot @RabbitListener, we are able to process the AMQP messages.
Whenever a message sent to queue its immediately publish to destination exchange. 
Using @RabbitListener we are able to process the message immediately.
But we need to process the message only between specific timings example 1AM to 6AM.
How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can take a look into *Delayed Exchange* feature of RabbitMQ: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#delayed-message-exchange

So, this way on the producer side you should determine how long the message should be delayed before it is routed to the main exchange for the actual consuming afterwards.

Another way is to take a look into Spring Integration and its `Delayer` component: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#delayer

This way you will consume messages from the RabbitMQ, but will delay them in the target application logic.

And another way I see like `start()/stop()` the listener container for consumption and after according your timing requirements. This way the message is going to stay in the RabbitMQ until you start the listener container: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#containerAttributes

Comment: Does it mean that in case of Delayer, the messages will be accumulated in memory?

Comment: Well, it doesn't if you configure a delayer with a persistent `MessageStore`. See those docs on the matter. But I'd prefer do not do `Delayer` since we have already a persistent store on RabbitMQ. So, for me other options are better. However I may miss something and there can be other ways to achieve your requirements. I won't mind to hear from other people.

Comment: I think running listener container in desired time intervals is best option here.

Comment: It's best (and simplest) to start() and stop() the container during the timeslot you want to process messages. Use the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry`.

Comment: We are using @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue(value = "${message.message-queues.audit-service}", durable = "true"), exchange = @Exchange(value = "${message.message-exchanges.audit-service}", durable = "true", type = ExchangeTypes.TOPIC), key = "${message.message-queues.audit-service}")) . How to use RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry here ?

Comment: The `id` on the `@RabbitListener` can be used from the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` to obtain its listener container for `start/stop` operations. Also pay attention to the `autoStartup` attribute on the annotation. See docs on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#async-annotation-driven and the `Container Management` paragraph.